# Img height not working

Tags: html, css

In CSS file, it writes as blow:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

In HTML, I write this:

```
<img height="1" width="340">
```

The result is `width:340,height:341` but I want the `height=1`.

The css file can not be modified and I must use it.
There has a lot of `<img>` tags and the height is different.

How to make the `height: auto;` invalid?

Comment: <img max-height="1" width=340"> should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
img, video {    max-width:100%; height: auto;}
img{
max-height: 1px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<img height="1" width="340" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write inline css like.

```
     <img style ="height:1px; width:340px;" >
```

Because inline CSS has more power than external or internal css